# Show the location options when manually searching location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, cllocationmanager

In text field when user start typing the location name, i want to show the list of locations name below as the user type, similar to search field like starts with alphabet 'A' show all option of 'A'. How can this be achieved.

**How can I get location names?**

Please guide for the above. And if any other thing need to ask please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to ask where i can get the location list.

Comment: @AppleDatasource: please mention this in your question :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Ya i missed that. thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use google api for that for sure.. Here is a link: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

`The Google Places Autocomplete API is a web service that returns Place information based on text search terms, and, optionally, geographic bounds. The API can be used to provide autocomplete functionality for text-based geographic searches, by returning Places such as businesses, addresses, and points of interest as a user types.`

You need to create your API Key using https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:18836829369. When you get your response you just need to look at `predictions` in your json response.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You Should use google place API. I dont know much about that but [this](http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/) link will be helpful.

Remember this for location search not for autocomplete searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below given function :

```
- (void)searchText:(NSString *)substring
{
        for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *curString = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]lowercaseString];
            NSString *searchString = [substring lowercaseString];

            if ([curString rangeOfString:curStringSmall].location == NSNotFound)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                //This means searched text is found in your array. you can store it in new array. Which will give you only the search criteria matched element.
            }
        }
}
```

You need to call this function from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

  [self searchText:txtSearch.text];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is second part of the question. However he knows this. He want the first part as **how to get location names in an array**